Does $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_{X,x}\simeq \hat{\mathscr{O}}_{Y,y}$ imply a local ismorphism in the analytic category?
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between two $\mathbb{C}$-varieties. If the induced map $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_{Y,y}\rightarrow \hat{\mathscr{O}}_{X,x}$ is an isomorphism for two closed points $x\in X$ and $y=f(x)\in Y$, does this imply an analytic isomorphism $f^{an}\colon U\simeq V$ for two open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ in $X^{an}$ and $V$ of $y$ in $Y^{an}$? Here $(-)^{an}$ is the analytification functor.
I know this is true when $X$ and $Y$ are nonsingular varieties (their tangent spaces are isomorphic). But how about general $\mathbb{C}$-varieties?

Yes: this implies the map is etale, which implies the analytification is a local isomorphism.
